# mpi4py on Ubuntu: pyconfig.h not found

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, mpi, mpi4py

I am trying to install MPI and mpi4py on an Ubuntu server in order to test some python code that I am running on my mac. I installed OpenMPI from source, and then downloaded a tar of mpi4py and attempted to run `python setup.py build`. However it fails with:

```
src/mpi4py.MPI.c:8:22: fatal error: pyconfig.h: No such file or directory

#include "pyconfig.h"

                  ^

compilation terminated.

error: command '/usr/local/bin/mpicc' failed with exit status 1
```

I also tryed installing MPICH with  `sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc` and then running `setup`, but it still gives me the same error.

I have searched the internet but still could not figure it out.

Is there a directory I am missing on my PATH?

EDIT: After some more searching it seems that pyconfig.h is supposed to be in `/usr/include/python2.7/`. This is the case on my mac, however, when I `ls`  the directory on my Ubuntu server it does not contain pyconfig.h. Is this the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found out that I need to install python-dev

Here is the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230995/how-to-fix-broken-python-installation#406698) I found that finally addressed the issue of a missing pyconfig.h.

Hopefully this will help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's still relevant, but for future people having this problem, be sure to apt-get the right version of python-dev using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python<version>-dev
```

For example, if you're using python3.5 in virtualenv, but your default computer python version is 2.7, typing only:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

will not help you, while typing:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

will fix the problem.